# How can I check Recv or send point of the socket is shutdown

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

In my server prosgram, I have shutdown the recv end of socket to refuse the incoming data.

Sometimes later in the code i wish to check if my recv end is closed or not. How can i check this? I didnt find anything interesting in getsockopt.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Why are you shutting down the read portion of the socket?  I assume this is a TCP socket, right?

Answer (score 1):

Probably by storing a flag alongside wherever you store the socket fd. Surely that will be more efficient than making additional syscalls...

Comment: Thanks R. I was thinking of doing the same way but wondered if there are any syscalls.

Answer (score 0):

How about `getsockopt(/*SO_CONNECT_TIME*/)`?... it will return `SOCKET_ERROR` of the socket isn´t connected...

I suggest You to use closesocket() on the socket to ensure it has been really closed and not only shut down.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to close only one end of the socket intentionally and doing shutdwon of the other end at later time(say send end) so as to clear my buffer.

Comment: Ok... So You do shutdown on the senders end , and closesocket on the receivers end?...

And at which end to You want to check for the "closure"?